# what is the purpose of conda inside a container?

Tags: python, docker, containers, anaconda, conda

I have seen many examples of dockerfiles with conda commands in them. And there are pre-build anaconda and miniconda containers. I must be missing something.

Doesn't docker REPLACE virtualenv and conda? Shouldn't I have all of my dependencies right in my dockerfile? I don't understand what I gain from adding anaconda here. In fact it seems like it makes my container unnecessarily bigger if I have to pull a miniconda container if Im not using all of miniconda's included modules.

Comment: While your points seem to be valid, I like to add that there are any different usecases for Docker and other usecases, other requirements or other knowledge levels might require very different approaches in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Not a terribly helpful comment. So you might use conda in a container because... "usecases"? Well you've peaked my interest. What do these usecases actually look like?

Comment: I did not have any special in mind but I can image some containing "only used conda before" or "I'm developing on Windows, and now I have to build a Docker thingy.".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Docker does not replace anything. It is simply one way to do things.

No, you should not have all of your dependencies right in your Dockerfile. I, for one, will be running `pip install` from a virtualenv without ever touching Docker/*conda unless I have a good reason. Your lack of requirements.txt is not a good reason :)

Conda came out in 2012 - well before Docker. Since Python has such a strong following in the non-programmer community, I rarely expect intelligible code, much less some type of DevOps ability. Conda was the perfect solution for this group.

With Docker, you can have a functional Docker environment with `FROM python:xx`, `COPY . /workdir`, and `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` (supposing you're using that file *ahem), but your developers will probably need a volume so they can work (so they need to know `--volume`. Also, if you're running Django you'll need ports configured (now they need `--port` and you need `EXPOSE`). Oh, also Django might need a database. Now you need another container and you're writing a docker-compose file.

But consider the following, from almost all of my professional (DevOps) experience IF you just include requirements.txt-

- I can use that file in my Docker container
- The requirements are all in one place
- I can develop on my local with a venv if I want
- Travis can install from requirements.txt and test on multiple versions without using Tox
- Setuptools handles that automatically, so my thing works with pip
- I can reuse those Dockerfiles (or parts) with ECS, Kubernetes, etc
- I can deploy to EC2 without using Docker
- I can install the package locally via pip

HTH - don't get too locked in to one piece of technology!

Comment: Dockers initial release was 2013. While this does make more sense to me, your argument is still essentially "use conda instead of docker for local development because developers can't be bothered to figure that out" right? Isn't one of the main selling points of containers consistency? You configure that django and DB container for local development so all the devs can develop on the same environment instead of configuring their own local django and DB setup (which is less complicated than compose??)

Comment: No, although I was pretty unclear.. Sorry about that. I vote for giving them a docker-compose file using hostnames so all they have to do is run `docker-compose up -d` and then point their browser at http://myapp. In this way I've replaced Conda with something equally simple (for them) but much more powerful. However I have to be careful with Docker on Mac because there are some networking snaggles that Docker says is Apple's fault.

Comment: Just thought of another thing, debugging support for containers isn't very seamless right now so running python locally to do something like attach a debugger i guess is much easier

Comment: Yeah, you'll see [these problems](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds) on your Mac and who knows what if you're running Windows. Then of course there are issues with different versions. If we're only worrying about developers, Docker is convenient because they only have to learn one piece of language-agnostic software and they don't need to know anything about the environment if they don't want to.